# Finding rows based upon the name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a table `table1` `a_id` as `PK`,  `hostname`, `create_dt`
Here `ipaddress` is `varchar`, `create_dt` is `datetime`

```
a_id    hostname              create_dt
9205    abc.com             2017-01-07 08:03:32
9206    cde                 2017-01-06 08:03:32
9207    abc2.com            2015-01-07 08:03:32
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another mysql table with following columns `id` as `PK`, `name`, and `created_dt`:
and `created_dt` is `datetime`

```
id      name                 created_dt
1       abc               2017-01-07 10:03:32
2       cde.com           2017-01-07 10:03:32
3       abc2.com          2016-11-07 10:03:32
4       abc3.com          2016-11-07 10:03:32
5       abc4.com          2017-01-06 10:03:32
6       abc5.com          2015-01-06 10:03:32
```

I want to compare table1 and table2 using `hostname` and `name` and bring all rows from `table2` which doesn't have hostname existing in `table1`

So from the above example, my query should return

```
id      name                 timestamp_val
4       abc3.com          2016-11-07 10:03:32
5       abc4.com          2017-01-06 10:03:32
6       abc5.com          2015-01-06 10:03:32
```

I have written the following query

```
SELECT *  
FROM table2.name a
INNER JOIN table1.hostname b
  where  a.name NOT LIKE CONCAT(b.hostname, '%');
```

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL`

Comment: can you help me with the query please?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.hostname, '.',1)=
                       SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.name, '.', 1)
WHERE t1.name IS NULL
```